# How to close a socket() if I used fdopen() on the socket descriptor

Tags: c++, sockets, fclose, fdopen

If I create a socket

```
sockfd = socket(...);
```

and then I associate it to a FILE stream by calling

```
FILE* f=fdopen(sockfd,"r+");
```

Should I call both `close(sockfd);` and `fclose(f);` or only `close(sockfd);`? What happens to the FILE structure if I call or not `fclose(f)`?

And (the most important), if I should call both of them, in which order they must be called? First `close()` or `fclose()`?

Comment: The question I marked as the original does not specifically reference sockets and has a long prelude, but the question is the same ("how do I close FDs wrapped in fdopen?"), and the answer is the same (fclose closes both the `FILE*` and the underlying FD).

Answer (score 2):

`fdopen()` wraps the file descriptor into a buffered io `FILE` structure, just as you had opened it with `fopen()`.

You should only call `fclose()`, this will both close the os file descriptor and free all associated structures and buffers!

Comment: @ScottFranco This would be a bug then. From the manpage: `The fclose() function flushes the stream pointed to by stream (writing any buffered output data using fflush(3)) and closes the underlying file descriptor.`